# how to call a function through a variable number of parameters

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++17, c++14

How to make a function call with a variable number of parameters?
to make it look something like this:

```
 if (f(args...))
```

Example to reproduce:

```
template <class callable, class... arguments>
void timer(callable&& f, arguments&&... args )
{
    f(args...);
}

class Client
{
    public:
    void receive(int, int)
    {
    }
    void sub(int x, int y)
    {
        timer(&Client::receive, this, x, y);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Client cl;
    cl.sub(1,2);
}
```

```
main.cpp:4:6: error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’
    4 |     f(args...);
      |     ~^~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: `std::forward` maybe??

Comment: No. if (f(std::forward<arguments>(args)...)) Error: must use ‘.*’ or ‘->*’ to call pointer-to-member function in ‘f (...)’, e.g. ‘(... ->* f) (...)’
   31 |             if (f(std::forward<arguments>(args)...))

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and show what exactly isn't working, including the complete error message if any. `f(args...)` is completely correct if `f` is a function and `args` a function parameter pack.

Comment: If `f` is not a function or object with `operator()`, but e.g. a member function pointer, then of course `f(args...)` will not work, for the same reason that `f(arg)` would not work with a single argument, but you are asking about functions which doesn't match the error you are showing in the comments.

Comment: Made a minimal example to reproduce

Comment: @Fedor, if that's minimal, I'm the incredible Hulk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `std::invoke(f, args...);` instead of `f(args...)`.¹

---

I've rarely used pointers to member functions, to be honest, but on [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer#Pointers_to_member_functions) I see that for a pointer to a unary member function `f` of a class `C`, being `c` such an object of class `C`, the call syntax would be `(c.*p)(x)`, being `x` the argument other than `this`/`c`.

This means that if you don't want to use `std::invoke`, you'd have to extract the first element of `args...` and the rest of them and pass them like this: `(first_of_args.*f)(rest_of_args...)`. While retrieving `first_of_args` is relatively easy (`std::get<0>(std::forward_as_tuple(args...));`), obtaining the pack `rest_of_args` requires some meta-programming trick, so I guess `std::invoke` is just the best solution. (The problem is exacerbated by the fact that you can't pass `some_obj_ptr->*some_pointer_to_member_fun` around, but you must apply it immediately. If that was not the case, you could think of constructing a `std::tuple` with all but the first element from `std::forward_as_tuple(args...)` and then use `std::apply` to pass them all to `first_of_args->*f`.)

---

Actually, an idea just came to my mind: using a generic variadic lambda to destructure `args...` in `first` and `rest...` in order to be able to meet the member function pointer call syntax. In code, you'd change your non-working `f(args...)` with the following

```cpp
    [&f](auto first, auto... rest){
        return (first->*f)(rest...);
    }(args...);
```

But this is, directly or indirectly, what `std::invoke` would do for you.

---

¹ As highlighted in a comment, you'd rather forward those args perfectly:

```cpp
std::invoke(std::forward<callable>(f), std::forward<arguments>(args)...);
```

Comment: It works, but is it possible without it? Doesn't want to use what I don't understand well

Comment: @Fedor You could specialize `timer` for the case when `callable` is a pointer-to-member-function, but that's exactly what `std::invoke` already does for you.

Comment: Both `f` and `args` should be `std::forward`ed.